# python socket - как сделать чтобы client не закрывал соединения

Tags: python-3.x, сокет

server.py

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(('', 9090))
sock.listen(10000000)
conn, addr = sock.accept()

print('connected:', addr)

while True:
    data = input("Text: ")
    conn.send(data.encode())

#conn.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('localhost', 9090))
data = sock.recv(1024)

print(data.decode())
```

[image: cmd]

Comment: Не закрывайте клиент. Такой же while True напишите, например

Comment: А чего вы ожидаете? Скрипт client.py заканчивает работу после выполнения своей последней инструкции - `print` - и Python закрывает и освобождает все ресурсы, использовавшиеся в скрипте.